# Live USB wont boot on BIOS system(PLS HELP!)

Tags: release-hera, boot, usb

Hello everyone Pls i request u guys to help me out eith this problem.
I am running a 2007 built desktop with the intel duo core processor @2ghz(64 bit cpu).
I recently made a live usb for elementary os.The ysb booted on my new laptop but it didnt boot on my desktop. I have installed ubuntu earlier on the same desktop and tge usb booted fine but in cade of elementary i am unable to boot from the usb even after using multiple tools and even after changing boot priority order but it always looks as if the computer didnt recognise the usb as bootable. Pls help me with this problem.

Comment: Is it a 64-bit CPU?

Comment: @DavidHewitt Yes its a 64 bit cpu